# append custom attribute to a dynamically created node javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, setattribute

I need to set the attribute of a node that I created through Javascript. However, it's becoming quite complicated because of where values are located in different functions throughout the script.

I have a constructor function:

```
function Todo(id, task, who, dueDate) {
    this.id = id;
    this.task = task;
    this.who = who;
    this.dueDate = dueDate;
    this.done = false;
}
```

Then I create span elements which hold the todos:

```
function createNewTodo(todoItem) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.setAttribute("id", todoItem.id);

    var spanTodo = document.createElement("span");
    spanTodo.innerHTML =
        todoItem.who + " needs to " + todoItem.task + " by " + todoItem.dueDate;
    li.appendChild(spanTodo);
return li;
}
```

Then I get values from  a form on the page which I use to set who, and task. And date, but that's a bit more complicated as I end up taking that value later in my code to get the difference between today's date and the date they entered.

```
function getFormData() {
    var task = document.getElementById("task").value;
    if (checkInputText(task, "Please enter a task")) return;

    var who = document.getElementById("who").value;
    if (checkInputText(who, "Please enter a person to do the task")) return;

    var adate = document.getElementById("dueDate").value;
    var reString = new RegExp("[0-9]{4}\\-\[0-9]{2}\\-\[0-9]{2}");

    var date = compareDates(date);
    var id = (new Date()).getTime();
    var todoItem = new Todo(id, task, who, date);
    todos.push(todoItem);
    addTodoToPage(todoItem);
    saveTodoItem(todoItem);
}
```

So, days is the value that I want here. I want to set dueDate to equal days so that I can use that value up in the innerHTML of the createNewToDo function.

```
function compareDates(date) {
  var days = Math.floor(daysCal);
  console.log(date);
  todoItem.setAttribute("dueDate", days);
  if (cdate < date) {
  console.log("you have" + " " + days + " " + "more day(s)");
  }
  else if (cdate > date ) {
  console.log("you are" + " " + -days + " " + "day(s) overdue");  
  } 
}
```

Any ideas on modifications to set dueDate to the value of days?

Answer (score 0):

Your `todoItem` is a JS object created by the `Todo` constructor, not a DOM node like `li` or `spanTodo`. Therefore, it has no `setAttribute` method, and if you want to set a property of it just assign to it (using a [member operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators)):

```
todoItem.dueDate = daysL
```